# Reduction of structure group of real vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I'm trying to show that the structure group of real vector bundles can be reduced to the orthogonal group. This is an exercise in Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Bott and Tu. The book gives a hint by asking to show that the general linear group is the direct product of the orthogonal group and the group of symmetric positive definite matrices. I proved this using the polar decomposition.

Now if I have a cocycle $ g_{\alpha\beta} $ I can write it as $ g_{\alpha\beta} = u_{\alpha\beta} p_{\alpha\beta} $ where $ u $ is orthogonal and $ p $ is symmetric positive definite. $ u $ and $ p $ vary smoothly with $ g $. What I need to do now is to define a map $ \lambda_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha}\rightarrow GL(n,R)  $ so that $ g_{\alpha\beta} = \lambda_{\alpha} u_{\alpha\beta} \lambda_{\beta}^{-1} $. I think $ \lambda $ should depend on $ p $ but I don't know how to make $ \lambda $ well defined and get the result.

Am I on the right track? Should I use another matrix decomposition? I looked at a list of decompositions and couldn't find a better match for this problem.

I'm interested in a solution that follows the hint. The book already contains a proof using a metric and partition of unity, so **the other question is not a duplicate**. I don't know Riemannian Geometry so please don't use it.

Thanks

Comment: You really don't need much "Riemannian geometry" to solve this question. You only need to establish that there exists a metric on any real vector bundle (over a paracompact space), which has a very simple and short proof. From there it's just algebra... But I'm interested to read a proof using some matrix decomposition.

Comment: If you want to follow the hint, the proof is based on the following general fact: Let $E\to X$ be a bundle with structure group $G$ and $H<G$ is a closed subgroup such that $G/H$ is contractible. Then there exists a reduction of $E$ to an $H$-bundle. On the other hand, there is a more direct proof (using a partition of unity) as Oliver suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reduction of a structure group.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204306/reduction-of-a-structure-group)

Comment: @studiosus Thanks. Do you have a reference that contains the proof in your first comment? Regarding the other question - the book contains the same proof. I'm interested in a proof based on the hint and without using a metric. I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterM: Then you should edit your question making it clear that you are not interested in a proof using a partition of unity (I will then try to remove my "close as a duplicate" vote). The proof I mentioned then is contained in Steenrod's "Topology of Fiber bundles" book. You need two ingredients: A reduction from a $G$-bundle to an $H$-bundle is equivalent to a section of the associated $G/H$-bundle. The space $G/H$ is contractible (actually, $R^n$ for some $n$) in your case. Now, read pages 54-55 of Steenrod's book (he avoids using partitions of unity).

Comment: @studiosus Thanks again. I'll check that book. You always seem to have encyclopedic knowledge of everything Topology and Geometry. If you don't mind me asking, do you study full time? For how many years have you been studying? I ask because I hope to get there some day...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is actually the Gram–Schmidt process, this gives the desired decomposition of a matrix $g \in GL(n)$ into $\lambda u \lambda^{-1}$, where $u \in O(n)$ in a natural way, i.e. the correspondence does not depend on choices and is smooth for a smooth family of matrices $g: U \to GL(n)$.

Comment: How are you using the hint?